# How to synch an existing SVN repository?

Tags: svn, working-copy, svnsync

I recently had to reinstall subversion on my hosting account. The repository I had setup is no longer considered working copy by the new SVN install. How can I added this repository back in to svn? I don't cant do an admincreate and copy it over. I have some checked out copies that need to stay in synch with this repository. How can I get the new SVN install up to speed with out compromising the checked out copy?

Comment: I believe you mix up "working copy" and "repository".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really messed my svn install up real bad. I reinstalled an older version or something and it wasn't recognizing my repository. Converted to a backup and then reinstalled svn to the newest version and things are cool now.

Answer (score 3):

`svn switch --relocate`

Comment: trying this : 
svn switch --relocate file:///home2/digizald/svn/dev file:///home2/digizald/svn/dev2

I got svn: '.' is not a working copy

Comment: If you're getting not a working copy, then you've got a different kind of problem.  Do you even have a .svn/ directory in your WC?